# How to create a draggable object in adobe animate?

Tags: adobe-animate

A rectangle that you can drag around.

I want to create a rectangle that I can move by clicking and dragging it. The rectangle stays in place after I stop dragging it.

Using Adobe Animate CC with html5 canvas, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
var root = this;
var rec = root.rec;

createjs.Touch.enable(stage);

rec.on("mousedown", function(e)
{
    e.currentTarget.offsetX = stage.mouseX / stage.scaleX - e.currentTarget.x;
    e.currentTarget.offsetY = stage.mouseY / stage.scaleY - e.currentTarget.y;
});

rec.on("pressmove", function(e)
{
    e.currentTarget.x = stage.mouseX / stage.scaleX - e.currentTarget.offsetX;
    e.currentTarget.y = stage.mouseY / stage.scaleY - e.currentTarget.offsetY;
});
```